# Create object from forEach

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, javascript-objects

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to rewrite this code as a single object creation:

```
my_array = [
  {key: 1, value: "foo"},
  {key: 2, value: "bar"}
];

let my_obj = {};
my_array.forEach((elem) => {
  my_obj[elem.key] = elem.value;
});
```

What I'd like to do is something like:

```
my_array = [
  {key: 1, value: "foo"},
  {key: 2, value: "bar"},
];

const my_obj = ...?
```

Is there a way to do a one-shot conversion that's equivalent to the `forEach` call?

Comment: You could use a `Map` instead (I have a one-liner in my head that would work).

Comment: You're describing `reduce`.

Comment: use reduce lke this `my_obj = my_array.reduce( (a, b)=>{ a[b.key] = b.value; return a;}, {})`

Comment: IMO, in this particular case a regular for loop or forEach is going to be the clearest thing you can do using only builtin functions. If you really want to make it one shot I would just put the loop in a nicely-named function.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to do it without a function call at all?

Comment: Yeah, mostly what I wanted was the ability to use const there plus hopefully cleaner code. There's no way to do it without a function call, is there?

Comment: meh, I forgot about `reduce`, but the map version is `new Map(my_array.map(x => [x.key, x.value]))`

Comment: *"what I wanted was the ability to use const there"* - Note that even with the code shown you could use `const` instead of `let`. Using `const` doesn't prevent you changing the contents of the object, it just stops you reassigning the variable to some other object.

Comment: Thanks, point taken about const. Also if someone with edit privs thinks of a better title for this post so other people can find it more easily, please feel free to change it

Comment: Would this work? `const obj = Object.assign({}, ...my_array.map(x => ({ [x.key]: x.value })))`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can achieve this using [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
var my_array = [{key: 1, value:"foo"}, {key: 2, value:"bar"}];
  
var my_object = my_array.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  prev[curr.key] = curr.value;
  return prev;
}, {});

console.log(my_object); // {"1": "foo", "2": "bar"}
```

---

Alternatively, using ES6 syntax:

```
const my_object = my_array.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    prev[curr.key] = curr.value;
    return prev;
}, {});
```

Comment: If you want it super lean, you could probably get away with `(prev, curr) => (prev[curr.key] = curr.value, prev)`

Comment: @JDB: In this case, i'd probably prefer `(prev, curr) => Object.assign(prev, {[curr.key]: curr.value})`, and `(prev, curr) => {...prev, [curr.key]: curr.value}` if the object spread operator is supported. More readable in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

In ES6, you can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
const obj = Object.assign({}, ...my_array.map(x => ({ [x.key]: x.value })));

// Or:
const obj = Object.assign({}, ...my_array.map(({ key, value }) => ({ [key]: value })));
```

This converts each `{ key: foo, value: bar }` to `{ foo: bar }`, then uses Object.assign to merge them into one object. (The [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) is used as Object.assign expects a variable list of arguments.)

Comment: what does the [key] do in second form?

Comment: @adaba It's a way to define a property inside `{ }` when the property name is a variable. For example, if you do: `const myVariable = "a" + "b" + "c"; const myObject = { [myVariable]: 123 };`, then `myObject.abc === 123`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function. It should work like this:

```js
my_array = [
  {key: 1, value: "foo"},
  {key: 2, value: "bar"}
];

let my_obj = my_array.reduce(function(obj, elem) {
    obj[elem.key] = elem.value;
    return obj;
}, {});

// my_obj = { "1": "foo", "2": "bar" }
```